# Modularizing Spring Security SecurityWebFilterChain

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

Our Spring Security configuration file is growing to big and we would like to break it apart into smaller parts. Right now we have the following:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/**"))
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);

    http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/serviceA/**")
            .hasAuthority("PROP_A");

    http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/serviceB/**")
            .hasAuthority("PROP_B");

    http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login", "/api/logout", "/api/forgotPassword", "/api/confirmForgotPassword").permitAll();

    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .requiresAuthenticationMatcher(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login"))
            .authenticationFailureHandler(CustomSpringSecurity::onAuthenticationFailure)
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(CustomSpringSecurity::onAuthenticationSuccess)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

    final SecurityWebFilterChain build = http.build();

    build
            .getWebFilters()
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(
                    webFilters -> {
                        for (WebFilter filter : webFilters) {
                            if (filter instanceof AuthenticationWebFilter) {
                                AuthenticationWebFilter awf = (AuthenticationWebFilter) filter;
                                awf.setServerAuthenticationConverter(CustomSpringSecurity::convert);
                            }
                        }
                    });

    return build;
}
```

We would like to use `securityMatcher` to break out `/api/seviceA/**` and `/api/seviceB/**` to there own `SecurityWebFilterChain @Beans`.

However the issue we have is the extra amout of configuration that exist in the configuration. We would like the end result to look like the following.

```
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChainForServiceA(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/serviceA/**"));

        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/serviceA/**")
                .hasAuthority("PROP_A");
        return http.build();
    }
```

And we would like all the other configuration to be implicit for the endpoint.

How would it be possible to make such a modularization in Spring Security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an interface like so:

```
    public interface HttpSecurityConfig {
        Consumer<ServerHttpSecurity> configuration();
    }
```

Then create a class that implements this for each of your endpoints which you can inject as beans:

```
    @Component
    public class ServiceASecurityConfig implements HttpSecurityConfig {
        @Override
        public Consumer<ServerHttpSecurity> configuration() {
            return (http) -> {

                http.authorizeExchange()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/serviceA/**")
                        .hasAuthority("PROP_A");
            };
        }
    }

    @Component
    public class ServiceBSecurityConfig implements HttpSecurityConfig {
        @Override
        public Consumer<ServerHttpSecurity> configuration() {
            return (http) -> {

                http.authorizeExchange()
                        .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/serviceB/**")
                        .hasAuthority("PROP_B");
            };
        }
    }
```

And finally amend your `SecurityWebFilterChain` so it injects all the beans of type `HttpSecurityConfig` and applies the configuration, something like this:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, final List<HttpSecurityConfig> httpConfigurations) {
    http.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/**"))
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);

    // This line replaces the individual configurations in your original question
    httpConfigurations.forEach(config -> config.configuration().accept(http));

    http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login", "/api/logout", "/api/forgotPassword", "/api/confirmForgotPassword").permitAll();

    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .formLogin()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .requiresAuthenticationMatcher(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login"))
            .authenticationFailureHandler(CustomSpringSecurity::onAuthenticationFailure)
            .authenticationSuccessHandler(CustomSpringSecurity::onAuthenticationSuccess)
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK));

    final SecurityWebFilterChain build = http.build();

    build
            .getWebFilters()
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(
                    webFilters -> {
                        for (WebFilter filter : webFilters) {
                            if (filter instanceof AuthenticationWebFilter) {
                                AuthenticationWebFilter awf = (AuthenticationWebFilter) filter;
                                awf.setServerAuthenticationConverter(CustomSpringSecurity::convert);
                            }
                        }
                    });

    return build;
}
```

Comment: Nice it works, however you have to remove http.securityMatcher(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/api/serviceA/**")); for each servie since you can only have one on each.